# How to reset inline css applied by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I've updated my self-made responsive menu but I have a problem with the menu disappearing when resizing.

When I downsize my window below 1100px width and open the responsive menu, everything is fine. However when I close the responsive menu  Jquery applies a display: none inline attribute.

This makes my screen disappear when I resize back to full width.

I need some way to override or remove the inline css with everything working properly. Can anybody suggest how to fix this?

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvQveZ)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button-open').click(function() {
            $('.navigational-menu').slideToggle('test');
            $(this).toggleClass('button-close');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're not using codepen properly.

Comment: Test the screen width in `$(window).on('resize')`

Comment: If you want help here, you need to submit your issue properly.

Comment: What am I doing wrong with codepen?

Comment: you're putting Evrything in one block, there is separate blocks for html,css and JS. if you dump like in one that will not work

Comment: My bad I will fix it and better my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no other inline css property try the updated Pen

http://codepen.io/valentinpalkovic/pen/rVOVjR

```
<script>
    ....
    $('.navigational-menu').slideToggle('test', function() {
        if($('.navigational-menu').css("display") == "none"){
            $('.navigational-menu').removeAttr("style");
        }
    });
    ....
</script>
```